# nginx conf does not work correctly

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have webserver application running on ports 82, 83 and 84, on same server.
Here is my nginx conf:

```
    worker_processes  1;
    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }
    #Server groups#
    http {
      upstream backend {
      hash $remote_addr consistent;
      ip_hash;
      server localhost:82;
      server localhost:83;
      server localhost:84;
      }
      server {
        server_name NGINX_server;
        listen 81;
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
      }
    }
```

I have 3 clients running on different IP addresses and I need that each client connect to different port, ie: 
client1 on 82, 
client2 on 83 and 
client3 on 84 
but it does not work.. Client1 is connected to 82 but Client2 and Client3 are connected to 83 (to same IP).
How to write conf file that each client (with different IP) connect to different port?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK above conf works perfect, I was not used 3 different IP address...